# Higher order function pseudo dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, higher-order-functions

I am trying to implement a sort of key-value store using higher order functions.
Now I beg your pardon for what presumably is a very messy piece of code that’s hard to understand, but here goes:

```
def empty_dic():
   return lambda x : False

def look_up(key,dic):
   return dic(key)

def add_elem(key,value,dic):
   return lambda x : value if x == key else dic(x)

def change_value(key,new_value,dic):
   return lambda x : new_value if key == x else dic(key)

mydic = change_value("colour","red",add_elem("brand","audemars",add_elem("colour","blue",empty_dic())))

print (look_up("brand",mydic))
```

Result: blue

I want the look_up function to return “audemars” in this case, but instead it gives me the colour of the last “add_elem” function.

Answer (score 2):

The error in `change_value` function, replace

```
lambda x : new_value if key == x else dic(key)
```

To

```
lambda x : new_value if key == x else dic(x)
```